# Disabling edit in a TTLauncherView

Tags: iphone, ios4, three20

I am new to three20. I was trying to fiddle around with Launcher. I was wondering if there is a way to disable the editing of the icon's location in TTLauncherView.

I searched and found an old post:

http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/b1a79ff4cb5e1983

However I don't see these changes in v1.1 or v1.02a.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/dcc9a6535ab031c8/e6da5bef5b1f01c8?lnk=gst&q=malolan#e6da5bef5b1f01c8

The answer is in the last post!

Comment: correct one
add implementation TTLauncherView (DisableEditing) 
- (void)editHoldTimer:(NSTimer*)timer { 
  _editHoldTimer = nil; 
} 

end 

at the very bottom of your class after end

Answer (score 0):

I added a `BOOL isEditable` property to my `TTLauncherView` subclass to make Mark's linked-to solution a little smoother. Added code here in case someone finds it useful.

**Edit:** oops, looks like this doesn't work if `isEditable` is true. Hm.

```
- (void)editHoldTimer:(NSTimer*)timer { 
    if (self.isEditable) {
        // use performSelector to remove the warning for calling a (Three20) private superclass
        [super performSelector:@selector(editHoldTimer:) withObject:timer];
    } else {
        _editHoldTimer = nil; 
    }
}
```